# Snake Identification - St. Louis, MO

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

We found this tiny snake in the finished part of our basement today. We live in the St. Louis, Missouri area.

[image]

[image]

The snake is dark greenish-grayish and has very faint lines running the length of its body.  Any idea if it is dangerous/what we should do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a juvenile [lined snake](http://www.whatsnakeisthat.com/?s=lined%20snake) (*Tropidoclonion lineatum*). The [What Snake Is That](http://www.whatsnakeisthat.com/category/region/midwest/missouri/) page for Missouri says they are native. In your photo, I see very faint black stripes with a central tan line, which matches a lined snake. Photos of juveniles seem to be rare though.

Lined snakes grow to about 2 feet long and are non-venomous. According to [this natural history page](https://pages.wustl.edu/mnh/snakes-missouri), the only venomous snakes in Missouri are pit vipers (of which 5 are native).